# I used the distributionUrl =https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip but after sync the layout files are still missing

Tags: android

I am having this could not find wrapper properties error in my android studio and when I am trying to fix this problem by using this----

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

distributionPath=wrapper/dists

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

Gradle sync starts but my layout file from the resource folder is still missing(Activity.xml). Please help me with this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpUKM.jpg)

Comment: please help me out with this